# TDS GetFilesToTransform

Tags: tds

I am playing around with the TDS task GetFilesToTransform. I want to try and transform files based on an environment variable that is not the current build configuration.

The default task definition in C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\HedgehogDevelopment\SitecoreProject\v9.0\HedgehogDevelopment.SitecoreProject.targets is this:

```
<GetFilesToTransform
  FileExtension="config"
  SolutionConfig="$(CurrentSolutionConfigurationContents)"
  Configuration="$(Configuration)"
  SourceWebProject="$(SourceWebProject)"
  WebProjectRoot="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\$(SourceWebPhysicalPath)"
  WebProject="$(SourceWebVirtualPath)"
  Condition="'$(ConfigTransformAvailable)' == 'true'">
  <Output TaskParameter="TransformFilesToRemove" ItemName="TransformFilesToRemove"/>
  <Output TaskParameter="Transforms" ItemName="Transforms"/>
</GetFilesToTransform>
```

I assumed that the **Configuration** property would allow me to pass in a different variable and pickup config transforms. I have duplicated this entry and created my own build task that looks like this:

```
 <GetFilesToTransform
  FileExtension="config"
  SolutionConfig="$(CurrentSolutionConfigurationContents)"
  Configuration="Local"
  SourceWebProject="$(SourceWebProject)"
  WebProjectRoot="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\$(SourceWebPhysicalPath)"
  WebProject="$(SourceWebVirtualPath)"
  Condition="'$(ConfigTransformAvailable)' == 'true'">
  <Output TaskParameter="TransformFilesToRemove" ItemName="TransformFilesToRemove"/>
  <Output TaskParameter="Transforms" ItemName="Transforms"/>
</GetFilesToTransform>
```

I am using **Local** as the configuration. However this is task still transforming using the build configuration value of **DEBUG** instead of **Local**. Any suggestions why this happening?

This is the build log:

```
11>                         Task  "GetFilesToTransform"
11>                             Task Parameter:FileExtension=config
11>                             Task Parameter:SolutionConfig=<SolutionConfiguration>
11><ProjectConfiguration Project="{135a1e1b-e091-439b-97d1-6f871280e339}" AbsolutePath="F:\TDS.Master.scproj">Debug|AnyCPU</ProjectConfiguration>
11><ProjectConfiguration Project="{b4239999-0ae1-438a-842b-094a33a8a2d1}" AbsolutePath="F:\Host.csproj">Debug|AnyCPU</ProjectConfiguration>
11>                             Task Parameter:Configuration=Local
11>                             Task Parameter:SourceWebProject={b4239999-0ae1-438a-842b-094a33a8a2d1}|EC.SWP.Common.Host\EC.SWP.Common.Host.csproj
11>                             Task Parameter:WebProjectRoot=F:\Host
11>                             Task Parameter:WebProject=/Host.csproj
11>    Transforms=
11>        App_Config\Include\_Common\Sites.config
11>                TransformFile=App_Config\Include\_Common\Sites.Debug.config
11>        web.config
11>                TransformFile=web.Debug.config
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the above example, the `SolutionConfig` XML attribute is constructed by the build process. Internally, this overrides the `Configuration` parameter when the build supplies the `SolutionConfig` value.

Remove the SolutionConfig property:

```
<GetFilesToTransform
FileExtension="config"
Configuration="Local"
SourceWebProject="$(SourceWebProject)"
WebProjectRoot="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\$(SourceWebPhysicalPath)"
WebProject="$(SourceWebVirtualPath)"
Condition="'$(ConfigTransformAvailable)' == 'true'">
  <Output TaskParameter="TransformFilesToRemove" ItemName="TransformFilesToRemove"/>
  <Output TaskParameter="Transforms" ItemName="Transforms"/>
</GetFilesToTransform>
```

And ensure that the file in the csproj has the dependant element:

```
<Content Include="App_Config\Include\_Common\Sites.Local.config">
  <DependentUpon>Sites.config</DependentUpon>
  <SubType>Designer</SubType>
</Content>
```

Comment: Do I need to remove this line:
SolutionConfig="$(CurrentSolutionConfigurationContents)"